# NGINX as reverse proxy to serve paths directly via url

Tags: nginx

I am looking to configure nginx to serve following requirement

We are serving individual websites at [www.company.com/mywebsites](http://www.company.com/mywebsites) and want to use nginx as reverse proxy to serve the same website on custom URL e.g [www.mywebsites.com](http://www.mywebsites.com)

I have configured dns of mywebsites.com to point to nginx server and following code block serves the home page of [www.company.com](http://www.company.com)

```
server {
    server_name www.mywebsites.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

however i am struggling to get the part of redirecting [www.mywebsites.com](http://www.mywebsites.com) to the [www.company.com/mywebsites](http://www.company.com/mywebsites) path. I have tried added proxy_redirect but that didn't help and also trying to add path in the proxy_pass doesn't work either as it then tries to fetch all of the components using [www.company.com/mywebsites/required/componenets.css](http://www.company.com/mywebsites/required/componenets.css) which results in 404 as the correct path is [www.company.com/required/componenets.css](http://www.company.com/required/componenets.css)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do this change:

```
server {
    server_name www.mywebsites.com;
    location / {
        rewrite /mywebsites/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }
}
```

However, I truly recommend that this issue to be fixed from the site code itself (I don't know what the site is developed with), as this might have unknown side effects on some URLs.